# Is there a way of collecting metrics from Spring XD to Graphite?

Tags: metrics, graphite, spring-xd

While reading the documentation for Spring XD I seen that it has a model for collecting metrics.

But when I looked into the code, I have seen that this is a custom implementation for Spring XD. None the less in the project dependencies there is codahale's metrics.

No it would be pretty useful to be able to add reporters (like the Graphite reporter which is also in the libs of Spring XD ) to the collected metrics.

But I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation on wether this is possible or how this should be done.

Does somebody have a hint how to do it, or if it is possible at the moment?

Thanks,
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring XD runtime components (XD admin, container and single-node JVMs) use Spring Boot internally. Spring Boot supports collection of codahale's metrics:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-code-hale-metrics

Since the `codahale` metrics jars are available in `$XD_HOME/lib`, all these metrics are `already` exposed at the Spring XD management endpoint.

By default management endpoint is enabled on XD admin. You can access them:

http://localhost:9393/management/metrics

For the container JVM, you can set the management port explicitly by setting XD_MGMT_PORT and access from '/management/metrics' endpoint.

You can refer to `monitoring-management` section in Spring XD wiki for more detail.